# Keep form open when clicking on another application

Tags: vb.net, winforms, window, window-position

I've got an application that I'm trying to use as a keyboard to type special characters. It currently has this function (not my code!):

```
Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
    Get
        Dim baseParams As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams

        Const WS_EX_NOACTIVATE As Integer = &H8000000
        Const WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW As Integer = &H80
        baseParams.ExStyle = baseParams.ExStyle Or CInt(WS_EX_NOACTIVATE Or WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW)

        Return baseParams
    End Get
End Property
```

This makes it so the form never receives focus, as I don't want to press a button on the form and then steal the focus. However, it also means that when I click outside the form, the window disappear, as it's positioned behind the focused application. The only way to use this program is to resize the application I want to type in, and position the window next to it. In other words, I can only use it like this:

[image]

So what I want to know is, how do I make it so I can position this application over the application I want to use it in, but when I press a button on the application, it still doesn't focus on that window?

Comment: What have you tried, right now I see nothing and that is not how SO works. Please update and inform us of what you tried and what doesn't work first before we help you.

Comment: It sounds like you need a toolbar and not a separate form. Wouldn't that work for you?

Comment: @Zaggler I don't know how to bring the Form to the front when it's also not allowed to be focused. How can I tell you what I've tried if I don't know how to try anything?

Comment: @GDS I don't know, can you create those with Visual Studio? How does a toolbar practically differ from a form?

Comment: A toolbar is a component that you add to a form. It is in the toolbox section in visual studio when you are in the designer view of your form.

Comment: @GDS But that's still part of a Form I've got to control, surely.

Comment: In general you can't bring something to front when it can't be focused...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `Me.Topmost = True` on your code or you can set the Forms Property to `TopMost` = `True`