# Impossible to set the window on top of the top of the top window?

Tags: vb.net, window, node-webkit

I have kiosk application, where i have already kiosk application running but on top of that window i need to put one of my window which is forever available no matter who ever is on top, that window has to be on top of the top of the very top window as always on top.

[image]
[image]

i tried several way but still it fails to stay on top of the window out all top of the window

Why is my application still unable to stay to the very top of the top?

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

  <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
  Private Shared Function SetWindowPos(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As IntPtr, ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer, ByVal cx As Integer, ByVal cy As Integer, ByVal uFlags As Integer) As Boolean
  End Function

  Private Const SWP_NOSIZE As Integer = &H1
  Private Const SWP_NOMOVE As Integer = &H2

  Private Shared ReadOnly HWND_TOPMOST As New IntPtr(-1)
  Private Shared ReadOnly HWND_NOTOPMOST As New IntPtr(-2)

  Public Function MakeTopMost()
    SetWindowPos(Me.Handle(), HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE)
  End Function

  Public Function MakeNormal()
    SetWindowPos(Me.Handle(), HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE)
  End Function

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.TransparencyKey = Color.LightBlue
    Me.BackColor = Color.LightBlue
  End Sub

  Private Sub Form1_LocationChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.LocationChanged
    Me.Top = 5
    Me.Left = 1185
    Me.Visible = True
    Me.BringToFront()
    'Me.TopMost = True
    Me.MakeTopMost()
    'Me.BackColor = Color.Transparent
  End Sub

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Shell("cmd.exe /c cd C:\ & taskkill /f /im testingVB.net.exe", AppWinStyle.Hide)
    End


  End Sub
End Class
```

**[EDIT]:**

I tried Me.TopMost = True and following event too, but still my RED cross is not on top of all the other on top windows. see below the RED is mine and all others are taking more priority then me to stay on top. how can i be on top of all those?

[image]

```
  Private Sub Form1_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.LostFocus
    MsgBox("lost")

    Me.Top = 5
    Me.Left = 1185
    Me.Visible = True
    Me.BringToFront()
    'Me.TopMost = True
    Me.MakeTopMost()
    'Me.BackColor = Color.Transparent
  End Sub

  Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

Me.Top = 5
Me.Left = 1185
Me.Visible = True
Me.BringToFront()
'Me.TopMost = True
Me.MakeTopMost()
'Me.BackColor = Color.Transparent
 End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have task manager set to always on top?

Comment: Sigh, there is no SuperDuperTopMostPlusOne property.  If there was the other app would already use it of course.   So using TopMost is completely pointless to implement a kiosk.  A correct kiosk prevents other apps from getting started, like the ones that want to be on top.  You do so with machine configuration, not software.  How to do so is well known, Google knows.

Comment: Sir, Logmein.com and there are many softwares which take over the SuperDuperGodMode to set there application always on top of all. i am just trying to get that like Logmein.com is doing when you remotely connect and Logmein.com shows a small popup and it always sits on top of everything. I am exactly trying to do that kind of popup. https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtPZT.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it a VB.Net program your pointing too? Change the `TopMost` property of that form to `True`

**Solution 1**

Or in your form add this `Me.TopMost = True` in your `Form_LostFocus` here is the link I also answer it the same as I given to you, you have the same problem

[Keep form open when clicking on another application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41214450/keep-form-open-when-clicking-on-another-application/41214521#41214521)

Dont forget that the form you will put the code is the form that you will show in your program

Update

Try This.

**Solution 2**

```
Dim form1 As Form = new Form
form.TopMost = True
form.Owner = Me
form.ShowDialog()
form.Dispose()
```

**Solution 3**

`Dim frmMessage As New Form()
frmMessage.Owner = form1
frmMessage.Show()`

Comment: you dont need to set a time `form_lostfocus` will do, take a look

Comment: If your `Me.MakeTopMost()` is causing the prob. then delete it, you have already the code so I think it will work.

Comment: you have the same problem as this one `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41214450/keep-form-open-when-clicking-on-another-application?noredirect=1&lq=1` what the name of that form? try to change the form propert of the form `RED Cross` to `TopMost = True`

Comment: If still the code doesnt work you can unaccept my my answer which you already done. Atleast I tried my best to help you

Comment: or put the `Me.TopMost = True` in `Form1_Load`

Comment: yeah i see it until now it keeps bothering me why? I wanna asume that you followed all of my instruction. Try to find another solution

Comment: Yeah Ive seen it everytime you open an application it always goes on top.

Comment: let see what we can do, stay over there BRB

Comment: right now remove the codes in your `Me.MakeTopMost`

Comment: Please see the edited answer, my tip to you is to delete the code inside form1_load then paste the code on Sol. 2 or Sol. 3

Comment: Solution 2, 3 should i put inside my existing Form1_Load() ?

Comment: Trial and error do as what I said above and also remove the code in Timer1 and LostFocus

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/E5Onxee.png - Sir same problem, your 3 solution still keeping the window behind the LogMeIn popup, see the screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131123/discussion-between-shadow-fiend-and-yumyumyum).